# Using Select By Attribute on shapefile in ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, shapefile

I am trying to take an existing shapefile and narrow down the attributes using the 'select by attribute'  The problem I am trying to solve is:  Find parcels that have an acreage >= 100.  The code I have is not narrowing down the search or showing up in arcmap.  Below is the code I have so far.

```
import arcpy

#Get Parcel layer
countyParcels = "C:\\Users\\Krystle\\Desktop\\WCGIS\\Geog485         \\final\\TarrantCoParcels\Parcels2013.shp"
nameField = "TAXPIN"

try:
    #Make a feature layer of parcels2013
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(countyParcels, "AllParcelsLayer")

except:
    print "Could not create feature layer"

try:
    #Create a seach cursor
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("AllParcelsLayer")
    #Call SearchCursor.next() to read the first row
    rows = rows.next()

    #Start a loop that will exit when there are no more rows available
    while row:
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("AllParcelsLayer", '"CALCULATED" >=100.00')
        #Print vaules in the current row
        print row.getValue(nameField)
        #Call SearchCursor.next() to move to the next row
        row = rows.next()

    #Clean up cursor and row objects
    del row
    del rows
    #Write the selected features to a new featureclass
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("AllParcelsLayer", "parcels_100plus")

except:
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Comment: What software suite are you looking to use? I'm assuming arcgis.

Comment: Yes arcgis and using python to write script

Comment: Are you able to do what you want within ArcMap? For instance, you can use a tool and then convert to the Python code, as outlined [here](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/04/02/the-power-of-the-results-window/).

Comment: I believe I know what to do, but it's the logistics of narrowing down using certain information.  I will try this though.  Thanks!

Comment: Well if you have questions about syntax, you can edit your opening post and we'll go from there.

Comment: I updated the post with the code that I have written...still has a glitch, but I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a search cursor to do what you want.  At the moment, you are running a selection on the entire layer for each row you have.  So, if you have 1000 rows, you are making a selection on the entire layer 1000 times.

Try getting rid of your search cursor and the `while` statement - just use the select tool.  I suggest you read the [help page on the select tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000071000000) as what you're trying to do is discussed there.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few issues:

`row` is undefined, which means that your while loop cannot loop over it. You need to define `row = rows.next()`, see [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000050000000).

You are missing a parameter for `SelectLayerByAttribute()`. You need to specify which type of selection you want (new selection, add to current selection, remove from selection).

I think you want your search cursor after you use `SelectLayerByAttribute()`. As Fetzer mentioned, you are pretty much running the same code the number of times equal to your feature count.

This might point you in the right direction:

```
import arcpy

countyParcels = "C:\\Users\\Krystle\\Desktop\\WCGIS\\Geog485\\
                 final\\TarrantCoParcels\Parcels2013.shp"
nameField = "TAXPIN"

try:  
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(countyParcels, "AllParcelsLayer")
except:
    print "Could not create feature layer"

try:    
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("AllParcelsLayer", 
                                            "NEW_SELECTION", '"CALCULATED" >=100.00')

    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("AllParcelsLayer")
    row = rows.next()
    while row:        
        print row.getValue(nameField)        
        row = rows.next()

    del row, rows

    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("AllParcelsLayer", "parcels_100plus")

except:
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
```